# how to show a jumping dots animation if the user doesn't write anything in 2 sec tip tap text editor?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rich-text-editor, tiptap, prose-mirror

I am trying to add dots animation on the tip tap editor. basically, my use case is when the user doesn't write anything then I want to show a dots animation to the user and then load some static sentence.
[image]

Comment: What is your purposed approach to this? What have you tried?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my question. i want to show the animation of the dots to the user if he doesn't write anything. And after 2 sec of animation, I will suggest some sentences to the user that will be some const or local storage saved content.@Disco

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write your own extension (you can always search the web for a extension, prosemirror plugings might work as well).

I would suggest that you familiarise yourself with the current extensions provided by tiptap and then extend on of the existing ones to fill your needs.

[Example to to use react components](https://tiptap.dev/examples/interactivity)

[Custom extensions Docs](https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions)

Based on you comment it looks like you want to customize the `Floating Menu` extension.
[Github](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/tree/develop/packages/extension-floating-menu)
[Docs](https://tiptap.dev/api/extensions/floating-menu)

Try and implement it yourself first, that way you can share code and might be able to get better help with your issues.